# How to get nexus project specific permissions running with repository targets?

Tags: nexus

I would like to set up our long running nexus (currently updated to 2.10) for project specific permissions, so that users are limited to access only a part of the repository.

I found [this article](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/02/how-to-partition-nexus-repositories-targets-privileges-and-roles) and [this one](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-repo-targets.html) which exactly match what I am looking for.

So I set up our config like this.

The regexp for us is: .*/de/mycompany/myproject.*/.*

But there is still one error:
I can log in with restricted view and in the search I just see the filtered artifacts. Which is great. But the bottom part of the UI where the repository tree is shown, is empty. Instead I get a 403 error. Looking in the system feed for authentication I find:

Unable to authorize user [myuser] for read(HTTP method "GET") to /nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/index_content/ from IP Address 192.168.0.41, user agent:"n/a"

"releases" is the name of our repo, for a part of which the user is permitted. So what to do to get access to this strange index_content? Do I need another privilege or role? Or another regexp? Using .*/index_content/.* does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as nobody knew a solution a did a lot of try an error at the weekend. Finally I ended with added a second regex just with a slash ("/"). Now it works as expected and documented in the referred articles.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you need to add permissions for the directories along the path for "browse storage" to work.

See here for more information:  https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21592111

Comment: Well, if this is a known requirement, it would be nice, if it would be added to your blog post and documentation.